# Can't change ServiceName using ConfigurationManager.Appsettings in the Initialize method?

Tags: windows-services, app-config

I modified my ProjectInstaller class to append the ServiceName with a value from the app.config file:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Varicent Upload Service - " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSetName"].ToString();
        serviceInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller,
        serviceInstaller});

    }
```

My app.config file has the following:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DataSetName" value="Activities"/>
  </appSettings>
```

The problem is that the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSetName"].ToString() throws a NULL exception.  Is there a limitation on when you can make a call to the app.config file?